# Javascript in CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

Statutory Disclaimer: New to JavaScript

**Form**: MyForm

**Fields**:

```
ntt_name
ntt_lookup1
ntt_lookup2
```

**Requirement**:

Read the value of ntt_lookup1 and ntt_lookup2 and get the name (not the id) and concatenate them and populate it on the name field (Primary Attribute).

I upload this as a Web Resource, associate it with the Form MyForm and add it to the onsave event.

I get the following error.

[image]

**Question**: What am I doing wrong?

**What I have done so far**:

1. Did a google search for the error and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128973/ie-throws-javascript-error-the-value-of-the-property-googlemapsquery-is-null) SO question. So, double checked for any missing brackets using both Notepad++ and by manually tracing it with hand.

---

**Code**:

```
if (typeof(CRMDynamics2011) == "undefined")
{ CRMDynamics2011 = {}; }

CRMDynamics2011.MyForm = {
    FormSave: function() {
        alert("Within Function FormSave");
        var lookup1 = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ntt_lookup1").getValue();
        var lookup2 = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ntt_lookup2").getValue();
        if (lookup1 != null && lookup1[0] && lookup1[0].name != null) {
            alert("lookup1 is NOT NULL");
            var value1 = lookup1[0].name;
        }
        if (lookup2 != null && lookup2[0] && lookup2[0].name != null) {
            alert("lookup2 is NOT NULL");
            var value2 = lookup2[0].name;
        }
        var fieldName = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ntt_name");
        fieldName.setValue(value1 + ' - ' + value2);

    }
};
```

Comment: what are you using to add it to the onsave? I would guess at 'FormSave()'. Try 'CRMDynamics2011.MyForm.FormSave()'.

Comment: I feel like an idiot! Thanks glosrob! If you make that an answer, I will upvote / mark it as accepted or if you are OK, I can flag it for Deletion (my preference - as it is not a valuable *programming* question as such). Either way, it is OK by me.

Comment: Try it first (might not be the issue)! And it isn't immediately obvious anyway so certainly isn't stupid. There might be a further issue if you are using rollup 12.

Comment: No, it worked perfectly fine. The alerts appeared, of course, I had other problems like the final value on ntt_name was "value 1 - [object Object]", but I guess I can figure that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using namespacing, you must fully qualify the method you want to call.

So in the form properties for CRM, for the OnSave event use

```
CRMDynamics2011.MyForm.FormSave();
```

CRM should then call your method when you click save.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it worked as soon as I used the Fully Qualified Name of the method.