# The value of the property 'openNewWin' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, controls

I have an asp menu and I am trying to set the navigateurl so that it opens in a new popup. The only problem is when I run the code it gives me the error:

Error: The value of the property 'openNewWin' is null or undefined, not a Function object

and in the address bar I have this:

javascript:openNewWin('/Controls/Financial/CustomerTypes.aspx')

This is the code that ads the url:

```
foreach (DataRowView childView in viewItem) 
{
   MenuItem childItem = new MenuItem(childView["MenuName"].ToString(), childView["MenuId"].ToString());

  //childItem.NavigateUrl = childView["MenuUrl"].ToString();
  childItem.NavigateUrl = "javascript:openNewWin('" + childView["MenuUrl"].ToString() + "')";

  menuItem.ChildItems.Add(childItem);
  AddChildItems(table, childItem);

}
```

Comment: Error message is clear, `openNewWin()` is not defined, `openNewWin()` is not a native JS or host object.

Comment: the openNewWin() is defined in the page, will that not work?

Comment: Then it's probably out of scope.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by out of scope, this is the function from the head of the page         <script type="text/javascript">

            function openNewWin(url) {

                var x = window.open(url, 'mynewwin', 'toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,left=0,top=0,resizable=no,status=no');

                x.focus();

            }

    </script>

Comment: When copy-pasting your code from comment, there was a couple of bad characters : `stat??us=no`. You maybe have them in the code too? They're visible in ANSI coded file, but not shown in UTF8 coded file.

Comment: It shows OK at my end but the code has been working fine, I have been using it in hyperlinks for weeks to open popups, the only difference was before I was using onclientclick and now it is in the navigateurl

Answer (score 0):

This can occur when your javascript code threw an error before to create the function definition, so when the code calls the function wasn't defined it display this message "property 'openNewWin' is null or undefined, not a Function object".

check this answer [IE throws JavaScript Error: The value of the property 'googleMapsQuery' is null or undefined, not a Function object (works in other browsers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128973/ie-throws-javascript-error-the-value-of-the-property-googlemapsquery-is-null).